# Chart.js gradient fill based on line position

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm building a chart using Chart.js, and trying to fill the space under the line with a gradient, however I want the gradient to be based on the line and not from the canvas. e.g. [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9qzL.png) is the standard gradient, and the gradient is based on total height and not line height.

What I'm trying to do is to have the gradient follow the height of the line. So far I've tried shadows and different gradient fills, but haven't been able to get the desired effect.
e.g. [This design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0W2a6.gif) is what I'm trying to achieve.

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById( 'large-line-FUA' ).getContext('2d');
var gradientStroke = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 100);
gradientStroke.addColorStop(0, "#2aabdb");
gradientStroke.addColorStop(1, "rgba(42, 171, 219,0.2)");

var myChart = new Chart( ctx, {
  type: "line",
  data: {
    labels: [ "JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY", "JUN" ],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: 'Cash',
        data: [ 12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3 ],
        borderColor: "#2aabdb",
        backgroundColor:gradientStroke,
        pointRadius: 5,
        pointBorderWidth:2,
        pointBorderColor: "#FFF",
        pointBackgroundColor: "#2aabdb",
      },
    ]
  },
  options: {
    legend: {
      display: true,
    },
    tooltips: {
      enabled: true,
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [
        {
          display: true,
          gridLines: {
            display: false,
          },
        } ],
      yAxes: [ 
      {
        display: true,
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true,
        },
      } ],
    }
  }
} );
```

```css
.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 15px auto;
}
.limiter {
  width:500px;
  height:500px;
}
```

```html
  
<div class="container">
  <div class="limiter">
    <canvas id="large-line-FUA"></canvas>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.0/Chart.js "></script>
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?